# Limitar el resultado de un formulario

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una calculadora que le diga a la gente a cuánta subvención pueden optar al plan Renove de calderas de la Comunidad de Madrid. Para ello deben ingresar el total de la factura o presupuesto y la calculadora desglosa el IVA y calcula el 25% de esa cantidad.

Esto lo he resuelto matemáticamente con una simple multiplicación *0,20661157 y me arroja el resultado perfecto.
El problema es que la subvención está limitada a 350 € y cuando ingresan una cifra por encima de los 1.700 € aprox. el resultado es mayor de 350. ¿Cómo podría limitar dicho resultado a 350 €?

No soy programador y el código lo he hecho con un complemento de Excel, así que no les va a gustar, pero si alguien me da una pista se lo agradecería infinito ya que llevo demasiado tiempo buscando y no encuentro nada.

El código que tengo es este:

```
<script>
    function calcule2(){
        var i=0; 
        for (i=0;i<= 1;i++) {
            calcule();
        }
    } 

    function calcule(){ 
        Excel2Html.E4.value= (Math.round((parseFloat(Excel2Html.E2.value)*0.20661157)* 100))/ 100;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hola Fran, bienvenido al sitio. Sería ideal que compartieras el código (no todo, sólo el par de líneas donde calcules la cantidad de la subvención). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información sobre eso. Aparte, lo que quieres hacer es probablemente bastante sencillo, mira la función [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/min) de JavaScript que puede serte de ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: No has compartido el código, pero puedes validar si el resultado es mayor de 350 muestre o limpie el campo o la celda donde se ingreso el valor así limitas el ingreso de números mayores, no se bien como funciona excel pero puedes limitar el valor de ingreso, si necesitas que el valor de ingreso sea cualquiera pero limitar el resultado , tienes que validar después de que se de el resultado comparar que si el resultado arrojado es mayor a 350  muestre algún tipo de mensaje.

Comment: Podrías utilizar un `<input type="number">`con un atributo `max="350"`. Esto de por si no soluciona el problema pero puedes añadir en el CSS algo así: `input:invalid{color:white; background:hotpink}`. Esto le dirá al usuario que algo no está bien. Por fin en el javascript puedes utilizar `addEventListener` y on "input" puedes decir `if(Number(subvencion.value) > 350){subvencion.value = 350}`

Comment: Puedes usar el método `Math.min(a, 350);`, donde a es la cantidad que calculaste. Este método devolverá el valor mínimo de los dos que le pasas, así que siempre te devolverá `a` mientras este sea menor a 350, y 350 en cualquier otro caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Creo que exactamente es lo que busco hacerlo con el método Math.min() pero no logro hacerlo funcionar. Entiendo que en mi caso sería Math.min(Excel2Html.E4.value, 350); pero no lo debo de colocar bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te dejo un ejemplo de como podría quedar, he modulado el código para que sea más legible.

Simplemente cuando se llama a la función que calcula la subvención comprueba si el valor es mayor a 350 si es así, retorna el máximo sino retorna el valor correspondiente.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Un saludo

```js
function calculatePlanRenove(){
  // Recoge el valor del input
  $total = document.getElementById('total').value;
  // Calcula la subvención
  $price = removeIVA($total);
  $totalSub = calculateSubvention($price);
  // Renderiza los resultados a la vista
  document.getElementById('priceIVA').innerHTML = $price;
  document.getElementById('subvention').innerHTML = $totalSub;
}

function removeIVA($total){
  $IVA = 1.21;
  return roundNumber($total/$IVA);
}

function calculateSubvention($price){
  $SUBVENTION = 0.25;
  $MAX = 350;
  $totalSub = $price * $SUBVENTION;
  return $totalSub > $MAX ? $MAX : roundNumber($totalSub); 
}

// Redondea a dos decimales
function roundNumber($number){
  return Math.round($number * 100) / 100
}
```

```html
<!-- LIBRERÍA EXTERNA CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="mb-4 mt-4">Plan Renove de calderas</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <h5>Introduce el total de tu factura o presupuesto:</h5>
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Total</span>
        </div>
        <input id="total" type="number" class="form-control"  pattern="^\d*(\.\d{0,6})?$" name="total" required>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="calculatePlanRenove()">Calcular</button>
    </div>
    <div class="coll-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="card  mt-3" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Resultado</h5>
            <p class="mb-1">Precio sin IVA: 
              <span id="priceIVA"></span>
            </p>
            <p>Total Subvención: 
              <span id="subvention"></span>
            </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Genial! está perfecta. Muchísimas gracias Patricia

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya sido de utilidad

Comment: @FranRuizMéndez Me alegra que te sirviera la respuesta de Patricia, no te olvides marcarla como aceptada y considera votar de forma positiva. De ese modo la publicación se considerará completa.